# systemd, docker, or systemd-journal (on stable CoreOS) using high CPU

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, systemd, coreos

I am running a CoreOS stable AMI on an AWS EC2 t2.micro instance. The only process running on this instance that doesn't run on a bare CoreOS install is nginx, which is only serving a few requests a day (not production) and uses 0.01% CPU according to my NewRelic Server.

What I'm finding is that every week or 2 I run out of CPU credits which makes the instance completely unresponsive.  It looks like systemd is the culprit per the graph below.

*Note: I recognize an easy fix is to upgrade the instance or not use a t2, but I'd like to get to the root of the problem and fix it instead of spending more money on an instance that's hardly get used. I'd like to be able to use t2.micro instances without worrying about core processes making them unstable.

Here is my 24-hour Process CPU usage graph from NewRelic:

[image]

Here are my AWS CloudWatch graphs for CPU credit balance, CPU utilization, and CPU credit usage over the same 24 hour span.

[image]

Here is my CPU credit balance over 2 weeks. You see it gradually decreases over time with a few sharp spikes/drops.

[image]

It may be worth noting that if I restart the instance and watch the processes via `top` the CPU usage of docker, systemd, and systemd-journal aren't as high. This is over an hour.

[image]

Here is systemd over the last 24 hours.  See it is using a consistent 2-5% CPU then spikes to 15%, which is right before I ran out of CPU credits, then after I restarted it it's been a steady <1%.

[image]